# OpenID Connect login returns Remote Error & ErrorDescription=427

Tags: oauth2, single-sign-on, open-id-connect

To provide authentication via the external OAuth2 authorization server, I'm trying to configure Auth. Provider as an OpenID Connect type.
After logging into the external server, I got an error page, with

> ErrorCode=Remote_Error&ErrorDescription=427

in the URL.
Also, nothing shows in the logs for the **'Execute registration as'** user.

Any pointers how trouble shoot this?

Comment: Have you already take a look on the HTTP requests that are exchanged between SFDC and your third-party IDP?

I would suggest to check what you get back when attempting a log in test on the `Test-Only Initialization URL` *(this URL is generated automatically when setting an Authentication Provider)*

Remember also to keep `Send access token in header` flag activated

Comment: Send access token in header" flag activated did it for me!